# Why isn't my Laravel one-to-one relationship working as expected?

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, relationship, one-to-one

I have two models, `Delivery` and `Shipment`.

`Deliveries` can have two distinct one-to-one relationships with `Shipment` : `OutboundShipment` and `InboundShipment`.

Here is how I am defining these relationships:

```
class Delivery extends Model
{
    public function outboundShipment() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Shipment', 'delivery_id', 'outbound_shipment_id');
    }

    public function inboundShipment() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Shipment', 'delivery_id', 'inbound_shipment_id');
    }

    public function addRelatedShipments() {

        $newOutboundShipment = new Shipment();
        $newOutboundShipment->status = 'Delivery Outbound';
        $newOutboundShipment->save();

        $this->outboundShipment()->save($newOutboundShipment);

        $newInboundShipment = new Shipment();
        $newInboundShipment->status = 'Inbound';
        $newInboundShipment->save();

        $this->inboundShipment()->save($newInboundShipment);

    }

}

class Shipment extends Model
{
    public function delivery() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Delivery');
    }   

}
```

After creating my `Delivery` object and saving it, I call `addRelatedShipments()`.

On one end, this works fine - if I call `$deliveries = Delivery::with('outboundShipment')->with('inboundShipment')->get();`, I get the list of deliveries and each delivery has `outbound_shipment` and `inbound_shipment` as properties on the models.

However, this doesn't work when I'm trying to include the delivery on shipments. If I call `$shipments = Shipment::with('delivery')->get();`, I get all shipments, and two fields are null: `delivery_id` and `delivery`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? I'd assume that at the very least, the `delivery_id` field shouldn't be null. As mentioned, I do call `save()` on the `Delivery` model before calling `addRelatedShipments()`.

Comment: I suppose you have to define the hasOne relation twice as well on Shipment Model, as you did on Delivery.

Comment: Hmm, I thought that might be the solution but wouldn't that go against my relation logic? Each Shipment only has one Delivery, and I would like it to use the same field `delivery_id`.

Comment: That's fine, however you have two different 'keys' on Delivery that reference Shipment. It (shipment) needs to know which one to work with. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L729

Comment: But the two different 'keys' on Delivery end up being local keys, so the Delivery model can have 'outbound_shipment_id' and 'inbound_shipment_id' at once... I'm definitely confused. The second argument is supposed to be foreign key (according to Laravel docs), which is why I set it as 'delivery_id', so that the Shipment model would use 'delivery_id' to refer to the Delivery... Or am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Look at Delivery from the Shipment Model. It has two ways to link to Delivery: inbound and outbound. When querying it, Shipment needs to know where to find Deliveries, is it an outbound ? an inbound? both?

Comment: Each shipment only has one Delivery. The shipment itself is inbound or outbound. Given ShipmentIn and ShipmentOut both using DeliveryA, shouldn't I be able to do ShipmentIn->delivery and ShipmentOut->delivery to both give DeliveryA?

Comment: This may help you to view it from another point: https://laracasts.com/forum/?p=431-eloquent-relation-setup-two-foreign-keys-to-same-table/0 It's still the same airport ;)

Comment: I think I get where that's heading, but the comparison is not the same. Each "Flight" may have a departure and arrival airport, but all of my "Shipment" models only have one delivery.

Answer (score 0):

Because your Shipment contains the `delivery_id` it has to define the relation to the Delivery model as a BelongsTo. Update your relation to be like this:

```
class Shipment extends Model
{
    public function delivery() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Delivery');
    }   

}
```

Comment: My bad. I initially had this and got the same result. I swapped to `hasOne` to try something different.